# Exception during saaj call for sending attachment through soap

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client, webservice-client

I am getting the following exception when calling webservice call through soap:

```
Mar 02, 2017 6:24:39 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl writeTo
SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1337)
    at com.abc.client.someClient.method(someClient.java:66)
    at virusscan.main.test.main(test.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: "text/plain" DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class java.io.FileInputStream
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.StringDataContentHandler.writeTo(StringDataContentHandler.java:139)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:896)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:329)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:973)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:284)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1328)
    ... 2 more
```

CAUSE:

Below is my code snippet. I am sending text file with datatype -text/plain. Can anyone help me to understand this.What should be wrong. I am using java 1.7

```
        SOAPConnection connection =factory.createConnection();  
        msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage reqMessage = msgFactory.createMessage();
        AttachmentPart attachment =  reqMessage.createAttachmentPart();
        attachment.setContent(fileStream,dataType);
        reqMessage.addAttachmentPart(attachment);

        StringBuffer sbuf=new StringBuffer();
        sbuf.append("\n").append(reqMessage.toString()); 
        System.out.println(sbuf);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reqMessage.writeTo(baos);                     
        sbuf.append(baos.toString());         

        endpoint = new URL(endPointAddress);

        responseMsg= (SOAPMessage)connection.call(reqMessage, endpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the exception it was expecting String as attachment content.

Try similar to this.

```
 AttachmentPart ap1 = m.createAttachmentPart();
 ap1.setContent(contentString, "text/plain");
 m.addAttachmentPart(ap1);
```

Comment: but i need to send the file through soap call. the file I am converting into fileStream     File initialFile = new File("C:/Users/...test.txt");
  InputStream fileStream= new FileInputStream(initialFile);

Comment: If you want to send content-type as text/plain content should be a string that's reason your program throwing error. You can convert file content to string and try to send it.

Comment: Its not alwasys i will get text/plai, i may get application/pdf ,application/octet-stream..etc etc. thats y i am sending fileStream. Ny ways  i tried for specific txt file converting it into String...but if i am doing so no response from from my service

Comment: If you want send in generic format without mentioning content type check this class javax.activation.DataHandler usage with SOAP messages.